# how to return boolean value based on condition check in array object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have object array obj1, obj2,

if the name of object cannot have `All` key name return true

if the name of object can have only one `All` key name and other object return false

if the name of object can have only one `All` key name and no other object return true

if the name of object has too many key name `All` return false

based on above conditions how to do in javascript.

```
function checkObj(ob){
  var result = ob.filter(e=>e.name=="All");
  if(result.length !== 1){
    return false;
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
}

var  obj1=[
  {id:1, name: "All", value:"all"},
  {id:2, name: "Sun", value:"sun"},
  {id:3, name: "Mon", value:"mon"},
]

var  obj2=[
  {id:4, name: "Thur", value:"thur"},
  {id:8, name: "Mon", value:"mon"},
]

var  obj3=[
  {id:1, name: "Thur", value:"thur"},
  {id:5, name: "All", value:"all"},
  {id:2, name: "Mon", value:"mon"},
  {id:6, name: "All", value:"all"}
]

var obj4=[
{id:1, name: "All", value:"all"}
]

var r1= this.checkObj(obj1);
var r2=this.checkObj(obj2);
var r3=this.checkObj(obj3);
var r4=this.checkObj(obj4);

Expected Output:

false
true
false
true
```

Comment: Change `if(result.length !== 1)` to `if(result.length > 1)`

Comment: also, I would use `.some()` for this case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I didn't see your comment before posting my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the array has any objects with `name = "All"`.

Then, `return true` if

- The array has `name = "All"` object and the array's length is `1`
- or the array doesn't have `name = "All"`

```js
function checkObj(arr) {
  const hasAll = arr.some(o => o.name === "All")
  return (arr.length === 1 && hasAll) || !hasAll
}
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
function checkObj(arr) {
  const hasAll = arr.some(o => o.name === "All")
  return (arr.length === 1 && hasAll) || !hasAll
}

const obj1=[{id:1,name:"All",value:"all"},{id:2,name:"Sun",value:"sun"},{id:3,name:"Mon",value:"mon"},],
    obj2=[{id:4,name:"Thur",value:"thur"},{id:8,name:"Mon",value:"mon"},],
    obj3=[{id:1,name:"Thur",value:"thur"},{id:5,name:"All",value:"all"},{id:2,name:"Mon",value:"mon"},{id:6,name:"All",value:"all"}],
    obj4=[{id:1,name:"All",value:"all"}];

console.log( checkObj(obj1) )
console.log( checkObj(obj2) )
console.log( checkObj(obj3) )
console.log( checkObj(obj4) )
```

Comment: if only one All present and has other objects return false, how to check this, thanks

Comment: @codecat What is the difference between point 2 and 3 in your question? *"if the name of object can have only one All key name and other object return false. if the name of object can have only one All key name and no other object return true*". I did not understand the difference

Comment: thansk for reply, have added the `obj4` example for "if the name of object can have only one All key name and no other object return true" `obj1` example for ". if the name of object can have only one All key name and no other object return true"

Answer (score 2):

You could take [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with a short circuit on counts over one.

```js
function checkArray(array) {
    return array.every((count => ({ name }) => (count += name === "All") < 2)(0));
}

var array1 = [{ id: 1, name: "All", value: "all" }, {  id: 2, name: "Sun", value: "sun" }, { id: 3, name: "Mon", value: "mon" }],
    array2 = [{ id: 4, name: "Thur", value: "thur" }, { id: 8,  name: "Mon", value: "mon" }],
    array3 = [{ id: 1, name: "Thur", value: "thur" }, { id: 5, name: "All",  value: "all" }, { id: 2, name: "Mon",  value: "mon" }, { id: 6, name: "All", value: "all" }];

console.log(checkArray(array1), checkArray(array2), checkArray(array3));
```

Comment: if only one `All` present and has other objects return false, how to check this, thanks

Comment: coun need the count variable outside of the function: `let count = 0; array.every(({ name }) => (count += name === "All") < 2); return count === 1;`